# Is there an adjective to call someone who gets bullied?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I need an adjective to call someone who gets bullied. An adjective for a victim.

Comment: Simply **bullying victim** or "bully victim" or "victim of bullying".

Comment: Or "the poor **victimized** soul who suffered the endless indignities inflicted by the cruel bully"

Comment: How about "bullied"?

Comment: I would go with victimized or preyed upon

Comment: As @DougWarren intimates, "bullied" *is* an adjective.  Same way you could say a "the poor ___ child" where the blank is *tormented*, *harried*, *pestered*, etc.

Comment: Do you mean someone who _has been_ bullied, someone who _tends to be_ bullied, someone who is _susceptible_ to bullying, or someone who (in your estimation) _allows himself_ to be bullied? These are subtle gradations, which might call for different adjectives.

Comment: @Chenmunka Are you calling Marie incorrect? : ) Of course you call someone an adjective.  Call me all the adjectives you want, I always say--just don't call me _late_ for dinner.

Comment: Evidence of attempts to use common online resources would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

The word bullied itself can be used in the exact context you requested.

He is **bullied**.

The **bullied** child is crying.

Answer (score 0):

A noun,   **goat**

> > (n) a *victim* of ridicule or pranks ([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/goat))

Comment: That is not commonly applied to someone subjected to physical bullying.